# Check if mariadb can be connected to and fix if not

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, database-connection

I am selecting and inserting data in a mariadb database with my node.js web app. In the mariadb node.js documentation (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/), it begins by querying the database with "SELECT 1 as val", and then after that, it executes the actual query, which is an insert in the example provided. It is my understanding that "SELECT 1 as val" is used to check a connection with the database can be achieved, because otherwise, if you were to query the database without checking, and a connection could not be achieved, the entire web app would crash.

My question is, is "SELECT 1 as val" the best way to check if a connection with the database can be achieved? It is true that if "SELECT 1 as val" fails, the web app will not crash? Also if a connection cannot be achieved, do I fix it? Do I have to redefine the 'pool' block again? Or the pool.connection block? Is there something I can do to restart the database server?

Comment: It is not your program's responsibility to restart a database server. The remainder of these questions deal with programming and should be asked on [so].

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with such a "ping".  Instead, always check for errors *after* running queries.

If the error says that you lost the connection, restart your transaction.

If the server is dead, you have no way to repair that.

Comment: How do I restart the transaction? Like this: conn.query(INSERT blah blah blah) or do I have to get the whole connection again with: my_pool_name.getConnection() .then etc..

Comment: @Normajean - Sorry, I don't know the details of node.js.